# Microsoft Xrm : Can't order by language an object of type IQueryable<KnowledgeArticle>

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, xrm

I am simply trying to order by their language a set of KnowledgeArticle.
My first guess was :

```
var SPRSet = _XrmServiceContext.KnowledgeArticleSet
            .Where(c => c.IsInternal == false)
            .Where(c => c.StateCode == Xrm.KnowledgeArticleState.Published)
            .OrderBy(s => s.LanguageLocaleId.Name)
```

This gives me the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException : 'The 'orderBy' call must specify property names.'

I then tried to load the LanguageLocale entity by doing the following :

```
SPRSet.OrderBy(s => _XrmOrganizationService.Retrieve(s.LanguageLocaleId.LogicalName, s.LanguageLocaleId.Id, new ColumnSet("name")).ToEntity<Xrm.LanguageLocale>().Name);
```

or similar:

```
SPRSet.OrderBy(s => _XrmOrganizationService.Retrieve(s.LanguageLocaleId.LogicalName, s.LanguageLocaleId.Id, new ColumnSet("name")).GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
```

Both giving me the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 : 
>    'KnowledgeArticle' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'name' and NameMapping = 'Logical'. MetadataCacheDetails: ProviderType=Dynamic, StandardCache=True, IsLoadedInStagedContext = False, Timestamp=62358974, MinActiveRowVersion=62358974'

When debugging, the LanguageLocale entity loading works fine when I evaluate the expression on the first item of my set:

```
var languageName = _XrmOrganizationService.Retrieve(SPRSet.First().LanguageLocaleId.LogicalName, SPRSet.First().LanguageLocaleId.Id, new ColumnSet("name")).ToEntity<Xrm.LanguageLocale>().Name
```

Other sorts on `Title` or `ArticlePublicNumber` work fine.

Comment: Did you check if someone created a `languagelocal` without a name? Your code looks fine and if you even can get the first `LanguageLocalId.Name` I'd suspect data being the problem.

Comment: I just checked and all articles seem to possess a correct `LanguageLocale` with a non empty `Name` property.
Edit : actually the language info is required when creating a new article on the CRM

Answer (score 1):

I fired up XrmToolbox's Metadata Browser to have a look.

The issue you're seeing may be related to the fact that an entity like Account's `name` field has the flag `IsRetrievable` set to `true`.

Whereas LanguageLocale's `name` has `IsRetrievable` set to `false`.

Account:

[image: Account]

LanguageLocale:

[image: LanguageLocale]

I'm not sure what you can do about this. You might have to come up with an alternative way to store the language info on the KnowledgeArticle.